# How to set default value for <project>.SetParameters.xml for deployment page

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msdeploy

During build msbuild creates deployment packages for several my web projects (and wcf services)  which I want to run from command line (as last step of automated build process) to deploy to several different servers.

The structure of IIS application folders is the same on each one.

My problem is that I cannot find how to configure (override default value of IIS application). It is in .SetParameters.xml, like:

which is not what I want.

I read that it is possible to create parameters.xml in the project and put there something like:

or some say

I'm trying this but it does not change content of .SetParameters.xml

Can you advice what am I missing, or/and alternative way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy the web application package manually—either by running the .deploy.cmd file or by running MSDeploy.exe from the command line—there's nothing to stop you manually editing the SetParameters.xml file prior to the deployment. However, if you’re working on an enterprise-scale solution, you may need to deploy a web application package as part of a larger, automated build and deployment process. In this scenario, you need the Microsoft Build Engine (MSBuild) to modify the SetParameters.xml file for you. You can do this by using the MSBuild XmlPoke task.

For more information, please refer to: https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/configuring-parameters-for-web-package-deployment